# Webpack SyntaxError - Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel-loader

I am setting up my ReactApp and just finished with it. So I wanted to make a settings class in a `appsettings.ts` file. So I can change some global variables easier.

But then all my issues started.

I know this problem is very common and there are tons of answers available but none of them have worked for me so far. I have searched through the internet to solve it but it still shows the same error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR in ../../../appsettings.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: [APP_DIR]\appsettings.ts: Unexpected token (2:11)

  1 | export class APPSETTINGS {
> 2 |     public static EMAIL_SENDER: string = "name@example.com";
    |            ^
  3 |     public static EMAIL_RECIPIENT: string = "name@example.com";
  4 |     public static YEAR: number = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  5 | }
    at instantiate ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:67:32)
    at constructor ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:364:12)
    at Parser.raise ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3364:19)
    at Parser.unexpected ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3397:16)
    at Parser.parseClassMemberWithIsStatic ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13888:12)
    at Parser.parseClassMember ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13773:10)
    at [APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13715:14
    at Parser.withSmartMixTopicForbiddingContext ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12617:14)
    at Parser.parseClassBody ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13694:10)
    at Parser.parseClass ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13669:22)
    at Parser.parseExportDeclaration ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14178:25)
    at Parser.maybeParseExportDeclaration ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14135:31)
    at Parser.parseExport ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14058:29)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13020:27)
    at Parser.parseStatement ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12917:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13497:25)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13489:10)
    at Parser.parseProgram ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12832:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12822:25)
    at Parser.parse ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14674:10)
    at parse ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14716:38)
    at parser ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:41:34)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:66:38)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:21:50)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
    at [APP_DIR]\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err ([APP_DIR]\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
 @ ./src/Page/Main/index.tsx 24:0-60 204:60-76 298:42-58
 @ ./src/App.tsx 5:0-31 14:38-42
 @ ./src/index.tsx 3:0-24 4:50-53

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 4752 ms
```

I got this error after I imported `APPSETTINGS` into my react app. If I delete the usage, then everything compiles fine, but with it, it just gives me this error

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
    const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv.development === true;
    const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv.production === true;

    return {
        target: 'web',
        watch: isEnvDevelopment,
        mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : 'development',

        entry: "./src/index.tsx",

        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: "/",
            filename: isEnvProduction ? '[id].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: isEnvProduction ? '[id].[hash].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].chunk.js',
        },

        devtool: isEnvDevelopment ? "source-map" : false,

        devServer: {
            compress: true,
            port: 9000,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
                https: true
            },
            historyApiFallback: true
        },

        resolve: {
            mainFields: ['browser', 'main', 'module'],
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
        },

        module: {
            rules: [

                // we use babel-loader to load our jsx and tsx files
                {
                    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-env"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(css|scss)$/i,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: isEnvProduction ? '[sha512:contenthash:base64]' : '[sha1:contenthash:hex:5]_____[local]'
                                },
                                importLoaders: 2,
                                sourceMap: isEnvDevelopment,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "resolve-url-loader",
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                outputPath: "binary",
                                publicPath: "/binary"
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                }

            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: isEnvProduction ? '[id].[hash].css' : '[name].bundle.css',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: 'src/static', to: '.' },
                ],
            }),
            new Dotenv({
                path: isEnvProduction ? path.join(__dirname, "./.env.automated") : path.join(__dirname, "./.env")
            }),
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "react-webapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "src/index.ts",
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack serve --env development",
  "build": "webpack --env production"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@aws-amplify/api": "^4.0.18",
  "@aws-amplify/api-graphql": "^2.2.7",
  "@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.3.8",
  "@aws-amplify/cache": "^4.0.20",
  "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.3.0",
  "aws-amplify": "^4.3.0",
  "classnames": "^2.3.1",
  "detect-browser": "^5.2.1",
  "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
  "ibantools": "^4.0.1",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
  "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
  "@types/react": "^17.0.26",
  "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
  "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
  "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
  "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
  "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
  "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
  "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
  "typescript": "^4.4.3",
  "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^3.4.0",
  "webpack": "^5.75.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.0"
}
}
```

Comment: You're not compiling Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed `@babel/preset-typescript` but it's not added to the loader presets.

```js
                {
                    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-typescript"
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                },
```

You may need to tweak the settings.

Comment: Thank you. I compeletly forgot about it. Appreciate the help.